# Getting error Cross-Origin Request Blocked in s3 bucket file uploading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new in s3 bucket AWs, When i try to upload file in s3 bucket i am getting error : `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxxxxxx.com`, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

CORS Configuration

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: You need to configure CORS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#example-scenarios-cors

Comment: I have added my same CORS configuration but it is not working

Comment: You are missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Seems like you're uploading it from some html form, S3 cors config looks good but S3 returns CORS header only if it's a preflight/option request or it's a GET with origin header, check that you're not receiving 4xx error when making putobject call.

Answer (score 0):

add the cross policy in your s3 bucket ( Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) )

```
    [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```